# Is there a way to use only 1 tag img in hbs to access different picture?

Tags: html, node.js, hbs

I'm creating a detail display for the consumer, and I want them to select on an object to view more information like a photo and price, among other things. However, the image remains static. Is there any way for me to obtain a different image for a different merchandise using the img tag? I attempted using the express path, but I believe I made a mistake.

Comment: [ask]..........

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.